# Relative version of Whitney embedding's theorem (reference needed)

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

One form of Whitney embedding theorem says that if $M,N$ are smooth compact manifolds and the dimension of $N$ is more than twice the dimension of $M$, then the space of embeddings $M\to N$ is open and dense in the Whitney topology.

I need a relative version of this: if further $f: M\to N$ is such that the restriction $f|_{\partial M}$ is an embedding (as a map $\partial M\to N$), is the space of embeddings $M\to N$ that coincide with $f$ on $\partial M$ open and dense in
$\{h\in C^\infty(M,N):\,\,h|_{\partial M}=f|_{\partial M}\}$?

Could you give me a reference or hint please?

Comment: Have you looked at chapter 3 in Hirsch, Differential topology? It's not quite what you're asking for, but it's related.

Comment: @Mike Miller Yes, I have. I believe that I could modify Hirsch proofs and somehow make it (if I spent enough time), but how should I cite such statement it in a paper? Just write that it is an "easy generalization"? Or outline the main ideas of such generalization..?

Comment: I am certainly the wrong person to ask about that - just wanted to mention a standard reference in case you hadn't seen it.

Comment: If you could give me a hint how my statement "easily follows" from Hirsch, I would be happy. Thanks for mentioning this reference, anyway :)

Comment: I have seen that both here and in some other questions you have offered a bounty but received no answer. Maybe you might be interested in my effort to collect somewhere unresolved bounties. For details see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/23715) and [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/43020/2016/7/26). Feel free to ping me here or [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/19138/martin-sleziaks-room) after you see this comment. (Since it is unrelated to the question, I prefer removing it after it served its purpose.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak I don't have energy to read all that discussion now but in general, I can only say that some of those past bounty-questions I don't need any more. So, if such a list is created, it should be based on "voluntarily adding the problem into the list by the author and still offering a reward for potential answers". That I think would make sense. Let me know if there would be some voting or whatever, on this.

Comment: @PeterFranek Yes, what you said is exactly what that room is intended for. By posting a question there a user is saying: "This is past bounty. I am still interested it. And if I get good answer, I might reward it with bounty." (The reason  pinged you here was in order to spread the word about the room - unless at least som users know about it, it will not work. I know that pings are inconvenience - so I apologize if the bothered you too much.)

Comment: I am facing exactly the same situation. How did you resolve it @PeterFranek?

Comment: I don't remember, it's long time ago :-( But I'm almost sure it's true. I think I found some related stuff for manifolds with boundaries in Kosinski, Differential Manifolds.. but not exactly this.